# Update Alasql database details based on existing data

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js, alasql

I have an Alasql Database that looks like this:

```
results
Name      Recieved
Bill      10/11/17 7:42 AM
Susan     10/05/17 3:43 AM
Sarah     10/04/17 2:08 PM
```

I'm trying to update it to convert the `Recieved` table and convert it into a unix timestamp.

This is what I tried:

```
alasql(`UPDATE result SET Recieved = ${new Date(Recieved).getTime()}`);
```

I get this error in Node:

`ReferenceError: Recieved is not defined`

How do I use the existing `Recieved` data from the database and perform mutations on it?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone runs into this problem alasql allows for custom functions like this:

```
alasql.fn.toTimestamp = function(date) {
  return new Date(date).getTime() / 1000;
}
alasql(`UPDATE result SET Received = toTimestamp(Received)`);
```